# how to view bot detection data in wso2 api manager?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

In Admin Portal I clicked on Bot Detection Data but it doesn't show anything:
[image]

I just want to see the list here.

How I can make it work and show the list just like the [documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-security/threat-protection/bot-detection/)?

Thanks a Lot.

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console or wso2carbon.logs?

Comment: Actually I copied a line from documentation in wso2-BotDetectionData.log.

and in console i got this : 

ERROR - APIUtil Error while invoking SP rest api :  404 Not Found
ERROR - GlobalThrowableMapper org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error while invoking SP rest api :  404 Not Found.

And how can i act as bot to just test it?

Thanks a lot for your comment.

Comment: Based on the error it seems the configurations are not applied properly. This error (`ERROR - APIUtil Error while invoking SP rest api : 404 Not Found ERROR`) gets printed when there is error when executing query on SP

Comment: Can you double check whether the configurations are correct. Specifically, please check whether `APIM_ALERT_BOT_DETECTION_EMAIL.siddhi` file has been copied to `<API-M_ANALYTICS_HOME>/wso2/worker/deployment/siddhi-files` directory. If not please copy it and try again

Comment: Ok I will check the configuration again. I did not copy the 'APIM_ALERT_BOT_DETECTION_EMAIL.siddhi' file to '<API-M_ANALYTICS_HOME>/wso2/worker/deployment/siddhi-files' directory. should i do that? I don't want the logs to be emailed I just want to see them in Admin Portal.